# Requesting help regarding a recursive query or CTE

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, adventureworks

I've recently downloaded the AdventureWorks2012 for SQL Server Management Studio, and found a few questions online regarding the database. I'm really stuck on one and desperately need some guidance;

> Display the managerial hierarchy from Ruth Ellerbrock up to CEO Ken Sanchez

Each person in the organization has an `OrganizationalLevel` in the hierarchy; with the CEO being `0`, Vice President `1`, Engineering Manager `2`, Senior Tool Designer `3`, and gradually going down. The lowest it goes is 4.

**What I'm doing:** I'm joining two tables, `[Person].[Person]` AND `[HumanResources].[Employee]` together to get the `FirstName, LastName,JobTitle, OrganizationalLevel`

```
Select [Person].[Person].FirstName
     , [Person].[Person].LastName
     , [HumanResources].[Employee].OrganizationLevel 
from [HumanResources].[Employee] 
JOIN person.person ON ([HumanResources].[Employee].[BusinessEntityID]=[Person].[Person].[BusinessEntityID])
```

It's my understanding that I need to use a recursive query or common table expression, but I really don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. And please feel free to ask any questions for more detail.

Thank you.

Comment: What field indicates who manages whom or who is managed by whom?

Answer (score 1):

The way the AdventureWorks sample works is by using the `HierarchyId` datatype on the `Employee` table - you really don't need a recursive CTE - a regular CTE will do.

Try something like this:

```
-- define the CTE to get the "anchor" data - the row for Ruth Ellerbrook
;WITH Anchor AS 
(
    SELECT
        p.FirstName ,
        p.LastName ,
        e.OrganizationLevel,
        e.OrganizationNode
    FROM
        HumanResources.Employee e
    INNER JOIN 
        person.person p ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE
        p.FirstName = 'Ruth'
        AND p.LastName = 'Ellerbrock'
)
SELECT 
    p.FirstName, 
    p.LastName,
    e.OrganizationLevel,
    CAST(e.OrganizationNode AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'OrgNodeString'
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN 
    person.person p ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN
    Anchor a ON a.OrganizationNode.IsDescendantOf(e.OrganizationNode) = 1
```

The outer `SELECT` will join the `HumanResources.Employee` and `Person.Person` tables and will fetch all rows where the `OrganizationNode` column of Ruth Ellerbrook is a *descendant* of the other row - e.g. it will list all immediate superiors for Ruth Ellerbrook, up to the CEO.

Comment: Can the condition be part of the join? Why must it be in the where clause?

Comment: @ErikE: right on - of course it can be the JOIN condition - too early in the morning still :-) Updated my response